# Parse a JSON String from Facebook Graph API using Python

Tags: python, json, facebook, api, parsing

I'm trying to compile all of my facebook friends user ids, but the output is difficult for me to work with. How can I simplify? It looks like this currently:

```
{
    u'friends': {
        u'paging': {
            u'next': u'https://graph.facebook.com/556702392/friends?access_token=-MYACCESSTOKEN-&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100005821213415'
        }, 
        u'data': [
            {u'name': u'Ian Fung', u'id': u'419972'}, 
            {u'name': u'Jason Turer', u'id': u'420694'},
            ...
        ]
   }
   ...
}
```

This is what I've been able to come up with:

```
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    contents = resp.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
    contents = error.read()

json_encoded = json.loads(contents)
print json_encoded["data"]["id"]
```

How can I store just the IDs?

Comment: What have you tried? Is the problem that you can't parse the JSON, can't extract the values from it, ...? Are you getting errors? Be more specific and provide your code.

Comment: It seems he needs to extract the ids. (He is using `json` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what data you want, but this list comprehension extracts `id` from `friends` `data`:

```
>>> json_data = {u'friends': {u'paging': {u'next': u'https://graph.facebook.com/556702392/friends?access_token=-MYACCESSTOKEN-&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100005821213415'}, u'data': [{u'name': u'Ian Fung', u'id': u'419972'}, {u'name': u'Jason Turer', u'id': u'420694'}]}}
>>> [x['id'] for x in json_data['friends']['data']]
[u'419972', u'420694']
```

Comment: Thanks - that did the job. How can I get rid of the u'' portion? I've tried 

for y in friends:
    y.replace("u", "")

but it does nothing

Comment: the `u` is notation for a `unicode` string. You can either just ignore it (it won't be there if you print the string), or call `str(y)`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you(and your given data is clumsy and not clear)

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('json_data')
decoded_data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(decoded_data)
json_data.close()
```

you can get the json values like this

```
decoded_data["friends"]["pagind"]["next"]
decoded_data["data"]["name"]
decoded_data["value"]
```